# Route does not work in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

All the directories are setup perfectly but still routing doesn't work. Pages 'folder' contain two pages 'addOrder.html' and 'showOrder.html'. I also included file 'angular.min.js' but still no results.

```js
//Define an angular module for our app
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

//Define Routing for app
//Uri /AddNewOrder -> template add_order.html and Controller AddOrderController
//Uri /ShowOrders -> template show_orders.html and Controller AddOrderController
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/AddNewOrder', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
  controller: 'AddOrderController'
 }).
      when('/ShowOrders', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
  controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
      });
}]);


sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope) {
 
 $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
 
});


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function($scope) {

 $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
    <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
     <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to include angular.route.js as the route has been separated into another module.
As quoted in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute),

```
<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add route resource file from
"http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"

and then in your module

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [ngRoute]);
```